# continued fraction multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, continued-fractions

After searching for a while, I wonder if a continued fraction representation exists for the multivariate Mills ratio $P(Z \geq x)/\phi_Z(x)$ where $Z \tilde\, N(\mu,\Sigma)$. The representation should, of course, be in terms of $x$, $\mu$, and $\Sigma$.

Such a representation is well-known if $Z \tilde\, N(0,1)$; see, for example,

[C-I. C. Lee., On Laplace continued fraction for the normal integral, *Ann. Inst. Statist. Math.*, 44(1):107–120, March 1992.](http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/044_1_0107.pdf)

(The same question is posted on stats stackexchange, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35006/continued-fraction-representation-of-the-multivariate-normal-distribution))

Comment: Also asked on stats.SE? http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/35006/6633

Comment: Indeed, I followed someone's suggestion by posting the question here. I have added links in each direction to avoid duplication of effort.

Comment: Cross-posting is [not encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/150510). Please choose one site and let moderators coordinate migration for you.